# do we need to make new folder for each api route in next js 13 App router

Tags: next.js13, next-router, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-app-beta, nextjs-api-router

I'm working on nextjs 13 App router version, In backend I have to make a route.js file within a folder         which act as path for API calls. The problem is I can only create 4 APIs per file that are GET,SET,POST and Delete  without any specific names like below. Is there any way to give the extra path in each API request so it will be easy to differentiate betweeen APIs

```
// Seeker SIGNUP
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
const response = NextResponse.next()
const body = await req.json();

}
```